# python: assign attribute value by name

Tags: python, python-3.x, self

As part of a bigger project in python3, I need a method in the spirit of to the following (not working) code:

```
class Qclass:
     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

def increment(Q, var):
    eval('Q.{} = Q.{} + 100'.format(var,var))

Q = Qclass(1,2,3)
increment(Q,'a')
print(Q.a)
>>> 101
```

I need this because I don't have prior knowledge on which attribute of Q has to be incremented. A  solution would be to declare specific functions for each attribute and use some selector, but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

Is there a tidy way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a **very bad idea** to **use `eval(..)`** (in almost any context). You can use `getattr(..)` and `setattr(..)` which are more secure:

```
def increment(Q, var):
    setattr(Q,var,getattr(Q,var)+100)
```

`getattr(obj,name)` and `setattr(obj,name,val)` get and set the attribute of an `obj`ect. So here you can get/set an attribute if you do not know the name in advance.

So the resulting code is:

```
class Qclass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

def increment(Q, var):
    setattr(Q,var,getattr(Q,var)+100)

Q = Qclass(1,2,3)
increment(Q,'a')
print(Q.a)
```

Comment: arrr, yeah! I have totally forgotten about setattr() getattr() . thanks. Although did you edit my question to put the def increment() in Qclass ? I meant it to be at root.

Comment: @Aderam: ah that was not the case? There was definitely something wrong with the indentation because `__init__` was in the same indent as `class`...

Comment: oups, sorry for the typo. Eveything is now exactlly as it should be :)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) would do:

```
def increment(Q, var):
    setattr(Q, var, getattr(Q, var) + 100)
```

yielding `101` for `Q.a` after your snippet executes.

`getattr` just grabs an attribute from an object by a given name (and allows for a default to be used if the attribute doesn't exist); similar to `Q.<val_name>`.

`setattr` performs the assignment, setting the attribute with the given name on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in function [vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) which returns a dictionary of variables declared in given scope. It's usage looks like this:

```
Q = Qclass(1,2,3)
try:
    vars(Q)['a'] += 1
except KeyError:
    Q.a = 1
```

Comment: Ingenious approach, didn't know about vars(). For the record I have benchmarked this solution against setattr(Q, var, getattr(Q, var) + 1). Seems that they are very close to equal in terms of computational time. Thanks

Comment: This approach only works on classes that have a `__dict__`, for classes without (e.g. using `__slots__`) this doesn't work. It's the equivalent of using `Q.__dict__['a'] += 1`